# Why does busybox ping expect root?

Tags: linux, busybox

Why does busybox ping expect root?

```
$ ping dec.com -c1
PING dec.com (216.239.32.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from any-in-2015.1e100.net (216.239.32.21): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=54.9 ms

--- dec.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 54.855/54.855/54.855/0.000 ms
$ busybox  ping dec.com -c1
PING dec.com (216.239.34.21): 56 data bytes
ping: permission denied (are you root?)
```

Comment: `ping` always requires root. Usually it's setuid.

Comment: @user253751: Linux added unprivileged IPPROTO_ICMP sockets a few years ago, but apparently Busybox hasn't learned about those yet. (iputils' ping no longer requires root.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was the external version, it should work as long it has CAP_NET_RAW capability or setuid, but in this case, `busybox`'s `ping` is built-in so you must run busybox as `root`.

You could try executing the external version if it exists, `/usr/bin/ping` or `/bin/ping`.